# Interpolate nonmonotonically sampled N-D array along one dimension

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation, resampling

I have a 3D volume (80x80x3 points) of measurement values ([646 2] values and timepoints). This data is not ordered and time between sample timepoints is non-equidistant. I would like to resample/interpolate to have less timepoints (say [0:0.1:1] spacing). All the data together becomes an [80 80 3 646 2] array where [: : : : 2] is time, which I would like to interpolate to.

My first try was with interp1 but the responses below already helped me further and now the problem Im not sure about yet is how to interpolate to time when its kind of sharing its dimension with measurement value? What I mean is [: : : : 1] are the values and [: : : : 2] are the timepoints.

Comment: `x` in `interp1` must be a vector

Comment: ah ok, so thats why my try did not work; I would have to make a 3 fold nested loop to go over every point. Maybe interp is not the right function to use then.

Comment: `interpn` may be of help

Comment: ah thanks, you and lennon are nicely helping me along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 % suppose your original matrix ranges from 1:80,1:80,1:3,1:646
 [x,y,z,t] = ndgrid(1:1:80,1:1:80,1:1:3,1:646);   

 % and you want to interpolate in finer constructed grids with interval of 0.1
 [xi,yi,zi,ti] = ndgrid(1:0.1:80,1:0.1:80,1:0.1:3,1:0.1:646);

 % v is your original matrix measurement matrix, vi is the interpolation
 vi = interpn(x,y,z,t,v,xi,yi,zi,ti,'spline');
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need! However the data is not ordered, which it needs to be for your solution to work. Havent figured out how to order it yet either, because if I add the time points it becomes a [80 80 3 646 2] array. Then ordering to the 5th or 4th dimension does not make sense because it contains both the measurement values and the time values. I think I need something inbetween 'sortrows' and 'sort' to sort it then. After that your solution works.

Comment: I don't think x,y,z,t needs to be sorted for the interpolation. You can try to directly add the coordinates of them into the ndgrid function. Provided your xi,yi,zi,ti are in the range of xyzt, interpn should work.

Comment: Thanks! However, i want to interpolate it to time and time will be in te same dimension as measurement value right? Wait, Ill try and clarify in my question.